# Regex custom start & end with quotes .Net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying a couple of regex´s to try to extract a txt from a file.

I try [with this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202328/regex-start-and-end-matching) with no sucess

lets say I have this string:

`This is _localizer["my test 1."]' (here I want 'my test 1.')`

or

`This is _localizer["my test 2."] And this is _localizer["my test 3."]' (here I want 'my test 2.' and 'my test 3.')`

In other others, the regex need to understand the begin anchor (_localizer[") and the end anchor ("]) and need to know that sometime there are multiple 'localizer' in the same line.

In the txt I want to extract sometimes will have / or \ and others characters that may will make regex fail.

What I am trying to do:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"_localizer[(.+?)]");
                var matches = r.Matches(txt)
                                .Select(xx=> xx.Value)
                                .Distinct();
```

cheers

Comment: You need to escape the `[` and `]` like `_localizer\[(.+?)\]`. To test it visit [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MNDUR0/1)

Comment: @Ackdari worked ok, but when there are 2 localizers in the same line, this regex only captures the first one

Comment: That is not true check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r99H0n) out. It works perfectly

Comment: @Ackdari you are right, my bad... make you commet a asnwer so I Accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regex string should look something like this:

```
new Regex(@"(?:_localizer\[""(.+?)""\])");
```

Let's break that down.

first there is `(?:` - this tells us that we require is inside the parenthesis for a match, but we don't want the data in our output

then `_localizer\[""` - this is just a literal match

next `(.+?)` - the `.` matches any character, the `+` tells us we want one or more, and the `?` makes the `+` lazy, meaning it will match only the least amount of characters it can. by surrounding this statement with `()` we at saying that this data is what we want

finally `""\])` - a literal for the closing brackets, and closing the starting parenthesis.

also to get that data into an easy list you will want to change your LINQ to:

```
var matches = r.Matches(txt)
               .Select(xx=> xx.Groups[1].Value)
               .Distinct();
```

Comment: Worked OK... but when there are 2 localizers in the same line, this regex only captures the first one. And its returning the txt and the anchors together

Comment: Did you make changes to the Select Statement?  the c# regex engine is weird in that it returns everything in the first group, so `Groups[1]` has the data you want. As for the multiple matches per line, i'll need to see more of your code, because the test program I wrote had no issues with that

Comment: its working fine... but when the end anchor is in another line, it´s not working...  like only the ] will be in another line... Chnaged the regex options to SingleLine but did not work

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oyDea6  is that what you tried?